# Reversing the ColorScheme used in an ArrayPlot and setting the font size in the color bar

Tags: plotting, options, version-9

I have a matrix of data that I am plotting via `ArrayPlot`.

```
FData = {{0., 0., 0.066812, 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0.479787, 0., 
   0.0683112, 0., 0., 0.}, {0.0669646, 0., 0.0697005, 0., 0., 0., 
   0.}, {0., 0.0683715, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}}
```

I would like to reverse the color bar colors in the Plot legend. I used:

```
ArrayPlot[
 FData,
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[{GrayLevel, {0, Max[FData]}}, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}], DataReversed -> False]
```

And this gives me:

[image]

The colors are flipped in this figure and I'd like the darkest to represent the highest number in my matrix.

When I try to "Reverse" my data (which doesn't seem sound to me) using the below snippet:

```
FData[[1 ;; 7, 1 ;; 7]]
ArrayPlot[
 FData[[1 ;; 7, 1 ;; 7]],
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[{GrayLevel, {0, Reverse[FData[[1 ;; 7, 1 ;; 7]]]}}, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}], DataReversed -> False]
```

And that gives me *nothing*!

### Edit/Errata

I have been using `PlotLegends -> 
 BarLegend[{GrayLevel, {0, 1}}, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}]` to set the font size. Based on the answers below, how can I go about changing the font size?

I know this is very basic but I can't quite figure out whats going on!

Comment: What Mma version are you using?

Comment: @belisarius *Mathematica* 9.0... Will make the edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
With[{g = GrayLevel[1 - #] &},
       ArrayPlot[FData, ColorFunction -> g, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{g, {Min@FData, Max@FData}}, 
                 LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Large]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: How do I change the font size of the text in the colorbar? I was using `BarLegend` for that purpose...

ArrayPlot[mat, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[{GrayLevel, {0, 1}}, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}]]

Comment: @drN See edit, please

Comment: Thank you. I would have never thought of this.

Comment: You might want to change `rData` to `FData`.. Thank you though, the essense of the answer still exists.

Comment: @drN yeah, I changed your FData for rData in my notebook. Always try to start your symbols with lowercase!

Answer (score 6):

With `ColorFunctionScaling -> True` (default), the data values are rescaled to between 0 and 1, which is then input to the `ColorFunction`. So the general solution to "reverse" the color scheme is to simply input `1 - x`, where `x` is the rescaled data point, as shown in belisarius' answer.

If you're using a built-in color scheme, you can use the `"Reverse"` property to automatically reverse the colors as in the following example:

```
With[{data = RandomReal[1, {10, 10}]},
    {ArrayPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "Temperature", PlotLabel -> "Original"], 
     ArrayPlot[data, ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Temperature", "Reverse"}], 
        PlotLabel -> "Reversed"]
    } // GraphicsRow
]
```

[image]

---

The documentation for the `*Legend` functions fully specify how to use the options to style them. Here's an example:

```
ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1,{10, 10}], ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Temperature", "Reverse"}], 
    PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{ColorData[{"Temperature", "Reverse"}], {0, 1}}, 
        LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Palatino", FontSize -> 14, Red], 
        LegendLabel -> "Colorbar", LegendFunction -> "Panel"
    ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: that's a great answer. How one does both "Reverse" and specify a range to normalize the scale? `ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Temperature", "Reverse",{0,1}}` does not work